# Palindrome tester diffuculty

Tags: java

I am making a palindrome tester, but I do not know how to get rid of punctuation. The program runs to show that words like "bob" and "yeetteey" are palindromes but does not recognize that m-a-m is a palindrome. How do I get it to work?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
//this is a palindrome tester
/**
 * YUHHHHHHHH YUHHHHHHH
 * @author its your boi, J. BACK at it again with another programming project
 *
 */

public class PalindromeTester {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //YOUR CODE HERE
    String word;
    int z;
    int y = 0;
    int i = 0;

    char letter;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    word = sc.nextLine();

    word = word.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    word = word.toLowerCase();

    z = word.length()-1;
    while (i <= z){

        if ((letter = word.charAt(i)) == (letter = word.charAt(z-i))){
            y += 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }

    if (y == (z+1)){
        System.out.println("The word IS a palindrome");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The word is NOT a palindrome");
    }

    }


}
```

Comment: works for me `Enter a word: m-a-m
The word IS a palindrome`

Comment: You're already using `word.replaceAll("\\s+", "")` to scrub the input of whitespace; if the idea is to ignore _all_ punctuation, you just need to scrub a little harder.... try `word.replaceAll("\\W*", "");` which will remove all "non-word" characters (a "word" character being a letter A-Z or a-z, a digit 0-9, or an underscore _).

Answer (score 0):

You already try to ignore punctuation characters with this line

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

where `\s+` matches any *whitespace*. Instead, you probably want to match *any character that's not a letter*.

Luckily, this is just a quick RegEx change:

```
word = word.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "")
```

replaces anything in the negated set of all lower case and all upper case letters; e.g. everything that's not a letter.

If you want different behaviour, e.g. for you wish for some other characters to count as characters in a palindrome, you can just add them to the set e.g. `[^A-Za-z0-9]` lets numbers through, and if you wanted, `[^A-Za-z\\-]` would let dashes through.